# NSData subdataWithRange crashing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsdata, nsrange, nsmutabledata

I have the following code  and I am getting an exception with it.

-[_NSInlineData replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000027ff2e0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Can someone point out the issue with this?

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] 
initWithLength:1000];

NSMutableData *d1 =(NSMutableData *) [data 
subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(sizeof(uint8_t),10)];
uint8_t i = 10;
[d1 replaceBytesInRange: NSMakeRange(1, sizeof(uint8_t) 
withBytes:&i];
```

Comment: `subdataWithRange:` returns a `NSData` object. `replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:` is a `NSMutableData` method.

Comment: any way to fix it without using extra memory?

Comment: Replace bytes in `data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subdataWithRange:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1410128-subdatawithrange?language=objc) returns an *immutable* `NSData` instance. It's a copy of the original data. If you want to replace data in that copy, without affecting your original `data` object, you can do:

```
NSData *tmp = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(sizeof(uint8_t),10)];
NSMutableData *d1 = [tmp mutableCopy];
```

If you want to modify the mutable `data` object instead, do so directly by calculating the correct range:

```
// Offset derived from your example code, lines 5 and 7.
NSUInteger offset = sizeof(uint8_t) + 1;
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(offset, sizeof(uint8_t));
[data replaceBytesInRange:range withBytes:&i];
```